# Images are aligned in Chrome & Explorer but not in Firefox

Tags: css

This is my website http://mokow.de/ I'm working on. I'm trying to keep everything aligned by using margins (9%) on both sides. Unfortunately, my last two images on the bottom doesn't really follow the general rule on Firefox ?

Could someone provide me a simple snippet as I'm sure I'm missing something there, I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for an hour now and to be honest it really frustrates me. :(

Thanks !

Comment: In my firefox everything is ok, if you can screenshot your issue and mention the classes you have issue with them !

Comment: 37.0.2 - firefox - also all ok

Comment: This is what happens on my firefox http://s3.postimg.org/opufza9wz/firefox.jpg 1680x1050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see your problem.
It is not about the margins, your problem is that your images are not big enough and when the screen is too wide, as they have the `max-width:100%` rule, then can't get bigger than they really are. They can strech but can't grow bigger than the width of the image so they don't blur.
You have 2 posible solutions:

1. change the max-width rule to `width: 100%`
2. or update your images and make them a little bigger.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick answer, unfortunately this do not seem to fixe the issue. Here is a more detailed picture of the issue: http://s16.postimg.org/6nvxtrzth/stack.jpg

Comment: Oh you ment the last pictures! I was refering to the group of 8 wich shows a 1px gap deppending on the size of the window!
Let me correct my answer

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick answer, I'll simply make them bigger.

Comment: Looks like the best choice!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for your case, I zoomed out the page and was able to reproduce your issue, I expected that the issue in screen resolution.

Update the following styles :

```
.wpb_single_image .vc_single_image-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wpb_single_image img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I just added `width: 100%;` to rules.